# Choice of a vector for supporting hyperplane theorem

Tags: convex-analysis

I'm having trouble relating the content on these notes [image: Stephen Boyd, Stanford] to these ones from MIT OCW [image: Dimitri Bertsekas, MIT, 2012] here.

Specifically, the question I'm having is the first set of notes describes the specific half space where $a^Tx \leq a^T x_0$ and the second concludes that any one of the half spaces must include $C$.

Generally, I'm having trouble visualizing this for all $a$. Does the theorem assume the same $a$ for all boundary points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both statements are equivalent. For any given point on the boundary, there is a hyperplane $a^Tx=k=a^Tx_0$ such that your set is in one of the half-spaces defined by it. You can always assume it is the "positive" half-space $a^Tx\ge k$, otherwise you replace $a$ by $-a$. Yes, the linear form $a$ depends on the point, it is different at every point, in general.